# Elasticsearch analyzed field which contains a value where it should match any given value

Tags: elasticsearch, keyword

Let's suppose that I have a following fields in my 'test' index in ElasticSearch:

categories -> field type is keyword, may contain a list of categories;

os_platforms -> field type is keyword, may contain a list of os platforms;

countries -> field type is keyword, may contain a list of countries;

Let's suppose that 'categories' field here has two values [c1, c2], 'os_platforms' field has a single value [p1] and 'countries' field has [ANY] value. Here I want this 'countries' field to match any given value in a search query. So for instance, if you supply c1, p1 and any country name in the query, it should have at least a single match since there is c1 and p1 values in the index.

Any ideas how can I achieve that in ElasticSearch?

Comment: Look up the elastic documentation for bool query

Comment: I know about bool query, I was just wondering if there is a special way to treat such fields so that the search query looks concise, simple and straightforward.

Comment: Like query_string query?